# Populate Last Cell With Query Function in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google

Looking for a way to populate an additional column in possibly a `QUERY` function. The extra column will only have as many rows as the first set of data. Example being my data is Sheet1!A:A

[image]

and then on Sheet2 using something like `=(query(A:A, "Select A"),[extra colB magic for 'TRUE'])` I'd like the output to be

[image]

I am aware that it only takes 15 seconds to populate ColB to TRUE, but I'm looking to avoid the manual touch of doing this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry. You totally lost me. If you want to **populate an additional column** then your second image should include column `C` with "TRUE" meaning `A`, `B`, `C`. To overwrite column `B` (as shown in your second image) is completely different. You also ask to _"Populate Last Cell "_  when you later ask for an additional column. Please edit your question or read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: @marikamitsos no you're spot on. I have one sheet with one column of data (ColA). I want to query it and then only populate the last column (ColB in this case) with "TRUE" but only as cells as ColA returns, so row count is equal. I'll update my question too.

Comment: _"you're spot on"_.  but still lost. :) I gave you option 1 OR 2 and your answer was yes. Please rephrase.  **Do you want option 1 OR option 2**. _"Yes"_ is **not** an option.

Comment: @marikamitsos, sorry for the confusion, was updating the main question when you replied. Looking for a way to just add an additional column with a preset value.

Comment: So... You want column column `A` + a new column `B` where  `B` shows `TRUE` whatever the value of `A` may be. **Yes or No?**. If no, what?

Comment: @marikamitsos Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to get the desired results would be:

```
=QUERY({'Sheet1!'!A1:A,ArrayFormula(IF(LEN('Sheet1!'!A1:A)<>0,REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT('Sheet1!'!A1:A),TO_TEXT('Sheet1!'!A1:A),"TRUE"),""))})
```

Functions used:

- [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [ArrayFormula](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [IF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)
- [LEN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094081)
- [REGEXREPLACE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)
- [TO_TEXT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094285)